# Drupal 7 how to add views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-views

m create one vocabularity locations(like delhi,bangalore,kerala) and im creates two content types one for user content(fields name,locations,map) type another for admin content(fields like locatoins,no of atms) type , these two contain one specific field that is locations field (vocabularity) now i have to display all details in one view means as table . ,columns are locations,name,no of atms. how to display in these all details in one view please help me im new to drupal thanks in advance. already im creating view no of atms values not displayingenter image description here

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a new view to show **content** and type as **all**

In create page give display format as **Table**

Then click continue and edit

Add new filter criterea **Content: Type**

On add you can select your required content types Choose **is one of** option and **check your required content types**

Then click Apply

After that you can add your required fields from the add in fields section of your view.

you can add contextual filters for filter according to taxonomy name.